# Windows shell script not able to make existing IE window visible?

Tags: windows, vbscript, wsh

I have been trying to create a really simple script to maintain visibility on an IE page but am currently unable to force the visibility or foreground position of an existing IE window.

I am able to successfully activate the window using WshShell.AppActivate() but it does not make the page foreground to a user. A sample from my code is below.

Basically the code loops until the user ends the notepad window. my confusion is specifically with why IE is not visible no matter what commands I send

```
Dim pressX
Dim FindProc
pressX = 1

' Create WScript Shell Object to access filesystem.
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'WshShell.Run "NoScreenSaver.txt", 2, 0

' Define Which process to seek for to terminate script
strComputer = "."
FindProc = "NoScreenSaver"

Dim objApp  : Set objApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Dim IE      : Set IE = Nothing
Dim objWindow 

' Loop start
Do

    ' Wait for 5 minutes
    WScript.Sleep 3000 '000

    For Each objWindow In objApp.Windows
      If (InStr(objWindow.Name, "Internet Explorer")) Then
        Set IE = objWindow
        Exit For
      End If
    Next

    ' check if specific notepad closed
    If WshShell.AppActivate("NoScreenSaver.txt") = True Then
         'WshShell.AppActivate("iexplore.exe")
         'wscript.echo FindProc & " is running"
    Else
        wscript.echo FindProc & " is not running" & vbCrLf & "Script will now end"
        pressX = 0
    End If
    IE.visible = True
    wshshell.appactivate ie.name
    IE.navigate "google.ca"

    ' Send dummy key
    WshShell.SendKeys "{F13}"

' repeat
Loop While pressX
```

I never wanted to use AppActivate to check for the specific notepad window either since it would take foreground. There is some information regarding using a COM wrapper but the COM wrapper approach is not possible within my constraints.

Comment: In your script, IE isn't actually IE. You declare a variable called IE, then you assign a Windows-object to it.

Comment: The windows-object I have assigned should correspond to any active IE browser window. In testing with AppActivate() the IE browser is affected as it recognizes something has changed (showing orange in the task bar) but does not become foreground.